# FIXED: Part of Wordpress page not showing up/not working

Tags: wordpress

FIXEDI have the following website page: #link
It should show posts of shows/movies, compared to the blocks at the homepage: #link

But for no reasons (no updates were done or plugins changed) it stopped working suddenly.

I looked into the code (there has been some editing to the code), and it probably is one of these lines:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'post_status'    => 'publish',
  'meta_key'=> 'draaidatum',
  'meta_query'     => array(
    array(
      'key'=>'draaidatum',
      'value'=>date('Ymd'),
      'compare' => '>=',
      'type'    => 'DATE'
    )
  )
);
```

When i removed this line, the page worked again (but not with the right functionality):

```
'posts_per_page' => -1,
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
posts_per_page' => -1,
```

to (for example)

```
posts_per_page' => 10,
```

-1 means shows all of the posts. There should be a time execution error while it try to show all the posts.

Comment: Than it shows the posts, but doesnt show all the categories. The code in my post is to generate the category selector on the top.
Also do you know, how could it work before then?